# How to find and remove all occurances of a function in a class in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been rewriting a code base and I've been trying to workout where in Eclipse I can remove all occurrence of a function and any argument/param it may have.

I'm not after clever regex solutions or anything like that, I'm sure the functionality would be in Eclipse, just not sure where ?:)

Many thanks

Just to clarify:

Here's an example...

The function's class myFoo no longer exists.  Because it has been refactored incorrectly before arriving with me.  Thus I want to search the code base (via an eclipse tool) and remove any line that uses the foo(String string) method from the myFoo class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hilight the object (method or variable), then select menu "Search/Refrences" or "Search/Declarations".  Do the changes manually, one at a time, so you can review each change. I would never make widespread code changes with a script due to the high probability of unintended consequences.

Comment: Another way to search it, would be a rightclick on the method-name > "Open Call Hierachy"

Answer (score 0):

I'd use replace from the edit menu with

```
replace='function name' to '// TODO:'
```

This would highlight them on the gutter. Select that line and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to delete that line.

Comment: Would take too long for a large code based scattered with functions that don't exist any more

Comment: Doesn't eclipse highlight the errors? Think there's no other way of doing it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It may be an option to remove the body of the function itself and then inline it via `Refactor->Inline`?

If needed you can of course save the function's code and insert it again afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of such a functionality within the JDT. But here is an automated solution you could use:

With [MoDisco](http://www.eclipse.org/MoDisco/) you can create a model of your java projects. Then you can use an [ATL](http://www.eclipse.org/atl/) refining transformation to remove all invocations of that method in that model. You can even replace the invocation with some other expressions, if you want to replace the functionality.

If your codebase is large enough than its probably a good idea to have a closer look at these eclipse projects.

Comment: Thanks, it's possible to replace it with regex pretty easily however I was hoping/assuming a nice simple GUI for removing defunct functions.

Answer (score 0):

Just type a 'MUST_BE_DELETED' or something similar at the beginning/middle/end of the method name (don't use the rename function) then eclipse will highlight all the places that call it in the problems window. When you've fixed all the problems you can go and delete the method.

If you have code in jsp pages then you'll have to manually search for those.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I used to do:

put your cursor at the method name, and press Control+Shift+g (in Windows), or you can do Search -> Reference -> Workspace.

This will search all reference to this method, in the workspace, and remove the reference manually

---

(Copied from my comment)

If you insist to have the "Remove" done automatically, there is another workaround (may not always works, depends on situation):

- make your method body empty,
- and then use Refactor -> Inline (you can even choose to delete method declaration)

But I believe there are some cases that this approach is not working. Worth a try to see if it works for your case anyway

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm asking, I want to find and remove them all automatically

Comment: I don't believe there is any "delete automatically" feature.  It is simply not going to work.  For example, if you want to remove the `int foo()` method, and if someone call it as `bar(foo());`, how can you expect Eclipse being able to correct remove the usage of `foo()` in such case?

Comment: Another workaround (may not always works, depends on situation) is to make your method body empty, and then use Refactor -> Inline (you can even choose to delete method declaration) but I believe there are some cases that this approach is not working.  Worth a try to see if it works for your case anyway

Comment: The functions class myFoo no longer exists.  Because it has been refactored incorrectly before arriving with me.  Thus I want to search the code base (via an eclipse tool) and remove any line that uses the foo() method from the myFoo class. 
Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Then, apart from a textual search, or visiting each error one by one, you have no other choice.  Regex may help, the problem is the parenthesis-matching logic.  Search on SO, I think there are quite a lot of similar discussion on bracket/parenthesis matching using regex.  However, I will say, for your case, just visit each error one by one and fix it may be easier

Answer (score -2):

Use ctrl+F short cut to open find/replace dialog.Than write your method name in space front of "Find" textbox .Do not write anything in "Replace With" textbox.
Then press "Replace All" button.

This is the most shortcut method.
enjoy :)